# R: How to remove a string containing a specific character pattern?

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

I'm trying to remove strings that contain a specific character pattern. My data looks somethink like this:

```
places <- c("copenhagen", "copenhagens", "Berlin", "Hamburg")
```

I would like to remove all elements that contain "copenhagen", i.e. `"copenhagen"` and `"copenhagens"`.
But I was only able to come up with the following code:

`library(stringr)
replacement.vector <- c("copenhagen", "copenhagens")`

`for(i in 1:length(replacement.vector)){
  places = lapply(places, FUN=function(x) 
            gsub(paste0("\\b",replacement.vector[i],"\\b"), "", x))`

I'm looking fo a function that enables me to remove all elements that contain "copenhagen" without having to specify whether or not the element also includes other letters.

Best,
Dose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the OP's code, it seems like we need to subset the 'places'.  In that case, it may be better to use `grep` with `invert= TRUE` argument

```
grep("copenhagen", places, invert=TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "Berlin"  "Hamburg"
```

or use `grepl` and negate (`!`)

```
places[!grepl("copenhagen", places)]
#[1] "Berlin"  "Hamburg"
```